# How to pass an image from Collection View to Detail VC in Xcode using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to pass an image from my Collection View (PortfolioView.swift) to another View Controller (PortfolioDetail.swift). My code for PortfolioView.swift reads:

```
import UIKit

class Portfolio View: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var array = [String] = []
    var name : AnyObject? {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")
    }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setObject(newValue!, forKey: "name")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        array = ["PortImage1","PortImage2","PortImage3","PortImage4","PortImage5","PortImage6","PortImage7",
    "PortImage1","PortImage2","PortImage3","PortImage4","PortImage5","PortImage6","PortImage7",
    "PortImage1","PortImage2","PortImage3","PortImage4","PortImage5","PortImage6","PortImage7"]
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BackgroundImage.png")!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
        cell.ImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.ImageView.frame.size.width / 2
        cell.ImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.ImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        name = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

My PortfolioDetail.swift code reads:

```
import UIKit

class PortfolioDetail: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var DetailImageView: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet var DetailLabel: UILabel!

    var name: AnyObject? {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BackgroundImage.png")!)
        DetailImageView.image = UIImage(named: name as! String)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

When I run this app I am able to get a display of my array of images but when I click on one of the images it doesn't display the image in my other VC. I think my issue is with the following line:

```
DetailImageView.image = UIImage(named: name as! String)
```

Comment: This is a misuse of `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @rmaddy how am I misusing NSUserDefaults? I followed a tutorial on this and he got it to work.

Comment: @kholl what do you mean by file system? I am new to this.

Comment: Just because you found a tutorial doing this doesn't make it right. There is a lot of terrible sample code on the Internet. 1) Using `NSUserDefaults` just to pass data between view controllers is a bad idea. 2) Storing large blobs of image data in `NSUserDefaults` is a really bad idea. Just pass the data directly from one controller to another.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay true. I am new to this. What is the easiest way to pass data from one controller to the next? Do you have any links that you can provide?

Comment: Add a public variable in your second view controller, and set its value from the first one when the push occurs.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo where in the code do I put this? Is this called segue?

Comment: You should review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?s=7|2.3903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving an `UIImage` in `NSUserDefaults` and then trying to use it as a `String` - this will not work, as these two types are not compatible. The easiest way to make things work, is to change
`name = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])`
to
`name = array[indexPath.row]`

This way, you will save the name of the image in `NSUserDefaults` and will be able to load the image based on it later.

---

Now, as it has been said in the comments - passing data between view controllers this way isn't really a good design choice. The best way would be to pass the `name` directly - there are two ways to do this, depending on how you move to `PortfolioDetail` view controller - by segue or "directly" (i.e. instantianting it yourself in code and calling `presentViewController`).

If you do this with segue you should add (if you don't have it) this method :

```
override func prepareForSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier") {
        let portfolioDetail = segue.destinationViewController as! PortofolioDetail
        portfolioDetail.name = self.name
    }

}
```

If you instantiate it directly it should look something like this :

```
let portfolioDetailVC = PortfolioDetail()
portoflioDetailVC.name = self.name
self.presentViewController(portfolioDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You'd also need to remove the custom `get`ters and `set`errs of the `name` variables in both view controllers.

Comment: this was extremely helpful. You broke it down in a way that I could understand it all and I appreciate your help. When I use your segue identifier method I get the error "type PortfolioDetail has no member 'name' " for the following code:

        PortfolioDetail.name = self.name

Comment: You can try changing it to be a`public` variable like this `public var name:AnyObject?` in `PortfolioDetail`, but it should work regardless (as long as both classes are in the same module, but I assume so) - I do hope you didn't remove it altogether after my remark about `get`ters and `set`ters, did you? I only meant that you wouldn't need the `get` and `set` parts of the variable declaration.

Comment: Yes I removed 
 get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")
    }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setObject(newValue!, forKey: "name")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
for both view controllers. is this correct?

Comment: You told me to change 'name = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])'
 to
'name = array[indexPath.row]' but I get an error that says " cannot subscript a value of type [string]"

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant about getters and setters. About the subscript error, I cannot see a reason for it, especially that it worked just before. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your code? Is `array` optional? You can try this `array?[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Thanks !! @Losiowaty . I just kept my original code and changed name = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
 to
name = array[indexPath.row]
it worked!